# Compatibility question

Tags: mountain-bike, cassette, derailleur-rear

I was wondering on a mountain bike what rear derailleurs work if have a 21 speed bike.

Additional information: 7 ring rear cassette and 3 in the front

Will an 8 and 9 speed rear derailleur work or how would i go about this getting a rear derailluer in that condition?

Comment: What brand are the shifters (or the existing derailleur)?

Comment: Can you post a photo of the derailleur? The way the derailleur mounts will make a difference.  Are you sure you have a 7 speed cassette or a 7 speed freewheel? If you aren't sure search "Do I have a freewheel or cassette" in the search box at the top of the page.

Comment: I cant post photos no camera and it is cassette just simply wondering if the speeds can go back of 8 and 9 speeds can work with a 7 chainring cassette

Answer (score -1):

I would say any 8 or 9 speed will work (same brand), you just need a 7sp shifter. 
The pulling ratio is controlled the by the shifter, so as long as the shifter has the same number of speeds as the cassette you should be ok.

Comment: Not categorically true. This answer for example could lead someone to try pairing a 1:1 SRAM derailer with their SRAM MXR Gripshift.